# Give ANT deployment a label

Tags: deployment, ant

Is there anyway to specify a name on an ANT deployment, instead of just an 18 character guid?  It would be especially helpful with for the new quick-deploy feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should address that to Salesforce.
You can log a case or suggest your idea on IdeaExchange.

It is not possible to change name for ANT Deployment currently.
Probably they would implement this option if you log a case or suggest your idea on IdeaExchange. They are constantly implementing some old most-voted user suggestions from idea exchange in new releases.